Efficient FIFO Data Storage and Deletion for Sequential Data
I’m building a device that needs to store data sequentially, retrieve it in chunks using FIFO, and then delete it. My device uses the ESP32-S3, and I'm currently using an SQLite build. However, as the database grows, performance degrades significantly. For example, deleting just 10 records from a database with 17,000 records takes more than a minute.
I'm considering switching to a different method for storing data. My current idea is to store chunks of data in separate files, and when I need to extract and delete them, just read all the data in a file and delete the file.
The data is stored on local flash memory, and each record consists of 5 integers. Records are generated when the device is disconnected from the internet, at a rate of approximately 15 records every 5 minutes. Losing internet connection may last for days, during which thousands of records can accumulate. Once the device reconnects to the internet, it needs to send the records to the server at a rate of 10 records per second, and delete the sent records as quickly as possible to avoid delays in flushing data.
Is storing chunks of data in separate files a good approach for this situation? What’s the best practice for efficient storage, retrieval, and deletion under these constraints?

What you describe is pretty much exactly how queues work in messaging solutions.

I will be happy to vote for reopening after you improved this question.

@DocBrown I improved the question.

@Navid: that's a lot better now, voted to reopen.
